# Doctrine appears to generate and save foreign key values for OneToOne, but not for OneToMany

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

When I save a composite Doctrine Entity with various associations, Doctrine appears to save foreign keys for OneToOne relationships, but not OneToMany.  I do not understand how and why it is doing that.

Here is some code to start with:

```
 /** @Entity */
class SelectionForm
{

    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="MotorFieldset", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     *
     * @var MotorFieldset
     */
    protected $motor;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="CasePoint", mappedBy="selectionForm", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     *
     * @var CasePoint[]
     */
    protected $casePoints;
}

 /** @Entity */
class CasePoint
{

    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="SelectionForm", inversedBy="casePoints", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     *
     * @var SelectionForm
     */
    private $selectionForm;

     /** @Column(type="float") */
    private $flow;
}

/** @Entity */
class MotorFieldset
{

    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $voltage;
}
```

When I populate the above `SelectionForm` object with values, and 4 CasePoint records, and then do `persist()` and `flush()`, I see something like this:

```
INSERT INTO MotorFieldset (voltage) VALUES ('380')
INSERT INTO SelectionForm (motor_id) VALUES (9)
INSERT INTO CasePoint (flow, selectionForm_id) VALUES ('140', NULL)
INSERT INTO CasePoint (flow, selectionForm_id) VALUES ('140', NULL)
INSERT INTO CasePoint (flow, selectionForm_id) VALUES ('140', NULL)
INSERT INTO CasePoint (flow, selectionForm_id) VALUES ('140', NULL)
```

I find it very interesting that the 2nd line above, the foreign key for `motor_id`, which is equal to `9`, is somehow inserted by Doctrine, despite just having it be created in line 1..
But the `selectionForm_id` is NOT inserted for `CasePoint` records, and is set to NULL.

Why does Doctrine properly generate foreign keys for OneToOne but not for OneToMany?

And how does Doctrine know to generate foreign key values properly for OneToOne?

Comment: You need to be sure that both $casePoint->setSelectionForm($selectionForm) and $selectionForm->addCasePoint($casePoint) are being called.  Typically, one of them would call the other to make transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you re doing something like:

```
$selectionForm->getCasePoints()->add($casePoint);
$casePoint->setSelectionForm($selectionForm);
```

To avoid this type of problems is very common add a method to do this in the entity:

SelectionForm.php

```
function addCasePoint(CasePoint $casePoint){
    $this->getCasePoints()->add($casePoint);
    $casePoint->setSelectionForm($this);
}
```